# Format Filter Date in React and Material UI Data Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm using MUI Data Grid Pro and I'm filtering the dates by `dd-mm-yyyy`
Right now, it is correctly outputted on the columns BUT on the filtering, it is not. It defaults back to the `mm-dd-yyyy`.

[image]

CLICK HERE ------> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hamilton-muz2h4?file=/demo.js)

```
const userColumns = [
  { field: "id", hide: true, filterable: false },
  { field: "group", headerName: "Group", flex: 1 },
  {
    field: "lastLogin",
    headerName: "Last Login",
    flex: 1,
    valueGetter: ({ value }) =>
      value ? format(new Date(value), `dd-LL-yyyy`) : "N/A",
    type: "date"
  }
];
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Phil. Sorry I forgot to add it. Pls check edited question

Answer (score 1):

After some [research](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3962) on this one, I've found that the filter panel date picker component currently used by the MUI Data Grid [GridFilterInputDate](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/3e7bfb2a3b11d3728892b245e70928c7669a0bd6/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/components/panel/filterPanel/GridFilterInputDate.tsx#L3) is essentially an [MUI `<TextField type="date"...`](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/3e7bfb2a3b11d3728892b245e70928c7669a0bd6/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/components/panel/filterPanel/GridFilterInputDate.tsx#L3) which uses [your browser's native date picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

The native date picker, if supported by your browser, uses the locale formatting for which your system is set.  For example, changing my locale to "United Kingdom" on macOS 12 (Monterey) and viewing [your CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hamilton-muz2h4?file=/demo.js) resulted in the format that you're looking for:

[image: MUI Data Grid with date filter]

You *could try* to wrangle a way to make the underlying input behave as you want (I was unsuccessful), by manipulating the input props, for example:

```
import {
  ...
  getGridDateOperators
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";

const userColumns = [
  ...
  {
    field: "lastLogin",
    headerName: "Last Login",
    valueGetter: ({ value } = {}) =>
      value ? format(new Date(value), `dd-LL-yyyy`) : "N/A",
    type: "date",
    filterOperators: getGridDateOperators()
      .filter(
        (operator) =>
          operator.value !== "isEmpty" && operator.value !== "isNotEmpty"
      )
      .map((operator) => {
        return {
          ...operator,
          InputComponentProps: {
            InputProps: {
              // ... some trickery
            },
            type: "date"
            // ... some trickery
          }
        };
      })
  }
];
```

But I'd probably just suggest looking into replacing the date picker used in the filter panel component entirely with something else like [MUI's Date pickers](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/).

```
  {
    ...

    filterOperators: getGridDateOperators()
      .filter(
        (operator) =>
          operator.value !== "isEmpty" && operator.value !== "isNotEmpty"
      )
      .map((operator) => {
        return {
          ...operator,
          InputComponent: YourDatePickerOfChoice
        };
      })

     ...
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Steve G I am terribly interested in the "// ... some trickery" part of your example. Can you please provide an example how the trick works?